# Rspec mocking with arguments and block

Tags: ruby, rspec3

Within my method I made a call to another method by passing argument and block like something like this

`analytics(url, params) do
  ExternalService.get(url, params)
end`

My question is how do I mock analytics with certainty that it is called with right arguments and block. Assuming it is a class method of SomeKlass

I can mock that analytics is called with right argument with

`expect(SomeKlass).to receive(:analytics).with(url, params)` but I cannot ensure it is called with right block.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the return value, not what is inside the block:

```
expect(SomeKlass).to receive(:analytics).with(url, params).and_return("return value")
```

Comment: I want to make sure it is called with the right block